# python idle how to create username?

Tags: python

Write a function called getUsername which takes two input parameters, firstname (string) and surname (string), and both returns and prints a username made up of the first character of the firstname and the first four characters of the surname. Assume that the given parameters always have at least four characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will want to make a function. (Please note any syntax I use will be for V2.7)

```
    def makeUsername(firstName,lastName):
```

Next, I would suggest a string to store the username that you will make.  You only want the first character and then the first 4.  Note the first and last names will be whatever you name the parameters.

```
    x = firstName[0] + lastName[:4]
```

Finally, printing the string and returning the string.

```
    print x
    return x
```

Then, when you call the function it will look something like this:

```
    makeUsername('John', 'Smith')
```

If you have any more questions, just ask!

Comment: So do I have to define that firstName is parameter1 and lastName is parameter2

Comment: @ivakukovska You can put any name you want for the parameter. The paramters act as variables kind of. So whatever name you put for the parameters will be what you use to call them in your function. I updated my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: i did this(not sure if is right), but is not working. I am new in this so I don't even know all of the basics   def makeUsername(firstName,surName):
    x="firstName[0]+surName[:4]"
    print('x')
    return('x')

Comment: @ivakukovska Very close! You do not need the quotes around the firstName part or around the x. You only use quotes when you have strings.  Here, you have variables.

Comment: As I added as you wrote, when I run it, it printed only x

Comment: def makeUsername(firstName,surName):
    x="firstName[0]+surName[:4]"
    print (x)
    return (x)
makeUsername('John', 'Smith'), and at the end i get firstName[0]+surName[:4]

Comment: You do not need the quotes here: "firstName[0]+surName[:4]". 
It should be just x=firstName[0]+surName[:4]

Comment: YESSSS!!!, FINALY, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!, By any chance can you help me with two more problems

Comment: You can select this as the best answer if you liked it :)  Go ahead and ask them on here and I can probably help answer them. I would make a separate question thread for each one.

Comment: ok, here is the other- Write a function called fib which takes as a parameter an integer, n, and returns the nth number in the Fibonocci sequence (see definition below). If n is zero or a negative number, your function should return an error message in the form of a string "Error: Invalid input.".

The Fibonocci sequence is 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ... where the first two numbers are 1, and each number beyond that is calculated as the sum of the previous two numbers (2 = 1+1, 3 = 2+1, 5 = 3+2, 8=5+3, etc).

Comment: Ask a new question on StackOverflow for them. Once you post them, it will be easier for me to look and respond to them.

Comment: I tried, but a person can ask only 1 question per 90 min, but i will try again

Answer (score 0):

This is how you build the string: `firstname[0] + surname[:4]`